# Real life use case for listener in Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am reading and trying my hands on Quartz Scheduler and its seems really a very good and easy to use platform.
I was reading about various listeners being provided by Quartz for Jobs,Triggers and well for Scheduler itself, but was unable to connect them with any real life use-case.

can any one give me some understanding with some use-case as where those Listeners can be used in real life application development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Quartz plugins<sup>[1]</sup> are built on top of listeners. This means that using listeners you can:

- log execution times and results of jobs/triggers (can't believe Quartz is not logging this out-of-the-box) to monitor job executions
- based on the information above you can build full monitoring solution with the ability to browse executed tasks
- you can create a listener that reschedules failed jobs after some time
- ignore job execution under some conditions

<sup>[1] [Quartz scheduler plugins - hidden treasure](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-plugins-hidden.html)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In the product that I work on, we have different features that are enabled/disabled based on the particular license of the customer.

We use a TriggerListener to evaluate whether a job should be executed based on the license.  If the customer isn't licensed for the particular feature, the trigger listener vetoes the execution of the job.

So instead of having to write something like the following at the beginning of the execute method for each job,

```
if (!license.isLicensed(token)) {
    logger.debug("Not executing job because of license...");
    return;
}
```

the logic can be centralized in the listener and an annotation can be added to the class of each job that specifies the license token.